# how to select, copy columns of different file to form new files

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have four files each contain daily station data.

- file 1: prec
- file 2: minT
- file 3: maxT
- file 4: wind

Here prec, minT, maxT and wind are files that store values of prec, minT, maxT and wind for stations 1 through n.

I want to store the data for each station like:

```
for station 1: prec minT maxT wind 
    station 2: prec minT maxT wind
    .
    .
    .
    .
    station n: prec minT maxT wind
```

#### EDIT #1

My four data fies look like as follows:

*Prec*

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0.254        0.254        0.254        0.254        0.254        0.254        0.254        0.254
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

*Tmin*

```
1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8
-23.349        -23.339        -23.327        -23.316        -23.303        -23.291        -23.278        -23.266
-23.682        -23.683        -23.685        -23.687        -23.689        -23.692        -23.695        -23.698
-24.302        -24.301        -24.3        -24.299        -24.299        -24.299        -24.3        -24.302
```

*Tmax*

```
 1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
-17.087        -17.082        -17.077        -17.072        -17.066        -17.06        -17.053        -17.046
-20.082        -20.095        -20.109        -20.124        -20.14        -20.157        -20.174        -20.191
-20.48        -20.481        -20.483        -20.485        -20.486        -20.488        -20.489        -20.49
```

*wind*

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
1.778        1.778        1.778        1.778        1.778        1.778        1.778        1.778
1.652        1.653        1.654        1.654        1.655        1.656        1.657        1.658
```

I want to format the data file for each point it's named with (that is for points 1 to 8) as below:

*1*

```
0        -23.349        -17.087        0
0.254        -23.682        -20.082        0
0        -24.302        -20.48        1.778
```

*2*

```
0        -23.339        -17.082        0
0.254      -23.683        -20.095        0
0        -24.301        -20.481        1.778
```

...and so on... to `n`.

Where the columns in each file would be: `nprec`, `nTmin`, `nTmax`, and  `nwind`.

Comment: I think the question is not very clear. Please supply examples of the contents of each of the 4 files and what you want the final result to look like.

Comment: Can you add a sample row or 2 from each of those files? Do they include the date the telemetry data was acquired?

Comment: Please double check what I've tried to clean up in your question still makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with `paste`, and possibly `join`.

```
paste file1 file2 > temp1
paste temp1 file3 > temp2
paste tmpe2 file4 > final
```

That should work if the files contain station 1 thru n data in order.  If not, you will need to get the files aligned somehow. If the "stattion n" notation is part of every file, you should sort them:

```
sort -o file1 file1
sort -o file2 file2
... and so forth
```

Then, you could do `join` instead of `paste` as above. `join` has some tricky options about putting lines in output that don't have a match in the other file, so you may have to read the `join` man page very carefully and experiment a bit to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you'd like to iterate through the 4 files, Prec, Tmin, Tmax, and wind and take the column data from each and merge it into a singe file per each column.

#### The approach

One way to achieve this is by using a Bash `for` loop, `paste` and `awk`. The approach would go something like this:

```
for i in `seq 8`; do
    ... do stuff ...
done
```

The primary purpose of this loop would be to step through the columns, 1 through 8.

#### Pulling out columns

The next bit we need to put together is the ability to pull data from a file, column-wise. One idea would be to use `awk` to do this.

```
$ awk '{print $1}' Prec
1
0
0.254
0
```

We can take this a step further and get it to skip the first line, which is the reference number of the column, like so:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print $1}' Prec
0
0.254
0
```

We can go even further by parameterizing the column we're printing by making it a variable that we pass into `awk` like so:

```
$ awk -v a=1 'NR>1{print $a}' wind
0
1.778
1.652
$ awk -v a=2 'NR>1{print $a}' wind
0
1.778
1.653
```

#### Puling out columns from multiple files

This bit is probably the least elegant bit to this solution, but I'm an `awk` noob, so when in doubt, go with a hack.

Here were using the output from multiple `awk`'s which pull the column-wise data from each file, and pasting them together using `paste`.

Here's 2 of the files, just so it's easier to see.

*column #1*

```
$ paste <(awk -v a=1 'NR>1 {print $a}' Prec) <(awk -v a=1 'NR>1 {print $a}' Tmin)
0   -23.349
0.254   -23.682
0   -24.302
```

*column #2*

```
$ paste <(awk -v a=2 'NR>1 {print $a}' Prec) <(awk -v a=2 'NR>1 {print $a}' Tmin)
0   -23.339
0.254   -23.683
0   -24.301
```

To get columns from all 4 files we'll simply expand on this approach.

set our index (`$i`) to 1.

```
$ i=1
$ paste <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' Prec) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' Tmin) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1{print $a}' Tmax) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' wind)
0   -23.349 -17.087 0
0.254   -23.682 -20.082 1.778
0   -24.302 -20.48  1.652
```

set our index (`$i`) to 2.

```
$ i=2
$ paste <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' Prec) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' Tmin) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1{print $a}' Tmax) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' wind)
0   -23.339 -17.082 0
0.254   -23.683 -20.095 1.778
0   -24.301 -20.481 1.653
```

#### Putting it all together

So now let's incorporate the `paste <(awk ..) <(awk ..) <(awk ..) <(awk ..)` into the `for` loop.

```
$ for i in `seq 8`; do 
  echo "## $i ##"
  paste <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' Prec) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' Tmin) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1{print $a}' Tmax) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' wind)
done
## 1 ##
0   -23.349 -17.087 0
0.254   -23.682 -20.082 1.778
0   -24.302 -20.48  1.652
## 2 ##
0   -23.339 -17.082 0
0.254   -23.683 -20.095 1.778
0   -24.301 -20.481 1.653
## 3 ##
0   -23.327 -17.077 0
0.254   -23.685 -20.109 1.778
0   -24.3   -20.483 1.654
...
```

I've added an extra `echo` above so that in the output it's easier to see which column is being printed.

#### Writing everything to files

By adding this bit after the `paste ...` command, we can write the results out to the individual files as you specified.

```
paste ... | tee out$i.txt
```

The whole thing as a one liner:

```
$ for i in `seq 8`;do echo "## $i ##"; paste <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' Prec) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' Tmin) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1{print $a}' Tmax) <(awk -v a=$i 'NR>1 {print $a}' wind) | tee out$i.txt;done
```

Which results in these files being written:

```
$ ll
total 48
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  71 Aug 21 23:17 out1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  72 Aug 21 23:17 out2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  70 Aug 21 23:17 out3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  72 Aug 21 23:17 out4.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  71 Aug 21 23:17 out5.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  71 Aug 21 23:17 out6.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  70 Aug 21 23:17 out7.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  71 Aug 21 23:17 out8.txt
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. Problem solved successfully.

Comment: @user45611 - wonderful. If you think this answer was helpful and/or solved your issue directly, please consider voting it up and accepting it.